# Determining whether the system will have a nontrivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, singularity-theory

Say I have a 3x3 matrix (a1 = 3a2 - 2a3), Will they system Ax=b have a nontrivial solution? Is it non-singular?

I realize nontrivial means an answer that is not a zero vector.

It must be the variables that are confusing me. I know that singular matrices need to have a 0 determinant, but not sure how to figure it out with this information. Thanks.

Comment: What does "a1 = 3a2 - 2a3" mean exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what a1, a2, and a3 are.  If they represent columns or rows of the matrix, then it will be singular because they are linearly dependent.

Comment: The question I have is vague. It just states I have a 3x3 matrix a. I know if the system only has a trivial solution , it is linear independent. Not sure how to figure that out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the notation correctly, $a_1=3a_2-2a_3$ means the rows of $A_{3 \times 3}$ are linearly dependent; this implies the matrix is [singular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularMatrix.html).

Whether or not $Ax=b$ has a non-trivial solution depends on $b$.

- If $b$ belongs to the column space of $A$, then there will be infinitely many (non-trivial) solutions.  By definition, there will be one solution, and $x+y$ will be another for all $y$ in the null space of $A$ (which is non-trivial, since $A$ is singular).
- Otherwise $b$ does not belong to the column space of $A$, so, by definition, there will be no solutions.

Comment: Great thank you. Do you mind explaining how you can tell if this equation here is linearly dependent? I am still trying to grasp all the terminology in my first year linear algebra class.

Comment: The way I understand it, the given equation $a_1=3a_2-2a_3$ describes a linear dependency among the rows of $A$.  It's not an equation that's linearly dependent, but the set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ formed by the rows of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Please give Rebecca credit by voting her answer up. It is just courtesy.

To expand on her answer, the system of equation will have a nontrivial soltio if and only if
$$
b_1 = 3b_2-2b_3$$
I.e. $b$ has the same linear dependence of rows.

Comment: And in which case there will be an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: yes but Rebecca already stated it. I did not want to take credit for it!